# Spring jdbc, jndi or standalone tomcat jdbc connection pool?

Tags: spring, tomcat, jdbc

I will use tomcat-jdbc connection pool in my application. There are two methods to add it:

1) insert as a resource into tomcat context.xml and reference it with jndi lookup from "org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean"

2)

```
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.h2.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:h2:mem:testdb" />
        <property name="username" value="sa" />
        <property name="password" value="" />
    </bean>
```

Which one is better? If there is not any difference, the second method will be preferreed, Because i dont want the app to be tomcat dependent.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy the app in a web app server like Tomcat, then solution 1 is better because it allows the sysadmin to configure a `DataSource` and give it to you. That way, they can do a lot of fine tuning and you don't have to care.

The second solution is better if you run your application stand alone (desktop app, command line tool, i.e. anything outside of a web container).

Comment: There is not a sysadmin, so i will do the configuration. I wonder if tomcat does anything else than the DataSource initialization and setting up parameters.

Comment: Tomcat does a ton of stuff, depending on the configuration of the `DataSource`. The point is: The configuration happens inside Tomcat and outside of your app. So the app doesn't depend on Tomcat. If you create the pool inside of your app, then you create a dependency.

Comment: Does Tomcat itself do a ton of stuff or tomcat-jdbc lib? If the tomcat-jdbc lib does, then when i create datasource by initializing from the inside standalone app or from the spring-in my second case-, there would be the same stuff done.

Comment: I you are alone in the world, then all this doesn't matter much. It becomes an issue when you have 10 applications running on a single Tomcat inside of a data center where you have several servers running Tomcats. Of course Tomcat config delegates eventually to tomcat-jdbc or some other library which you installed into `server/lib/`. The main point is: If you use JNDI and let Tomcat do the work, you don't have to recompile your code to modify the data source.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how much control the application needs to have on the connection pool and if you want/need to share it between multiple applications.

If there are more than one applications sharing the pool, you should go for the 1st method. If it is going to be used by the single application and the application needs to change the configuration, better go for method 2.

Comment: There is just one application will use pool. I just wonder if tomcat does anything else in addition to method 2.